# how to implement object merge

Tags: java, merge, compare

I have composite objects, that compound of other objects. Two clients changed the objects internals in two separate copies, and I want to merge those changes, what is the best approach to do so, and is there a framework to support such operation?
Thanks, Ohad.

Comment: What do you mean by two clients? Is this a distributed app and these objects might be on different machines with different users?

Comment: No, they are all in the same jvm eventually. the clients use tcp to 'tell' what they would like to change.

Comment: If it is always a same JVM then can you create a singleton for that object? That ways you always update only that object. Also if these objects represent some real world entities like let's say, a user, then you can create a hashmap of cached objects where you will perform merge operations!

Comment: singelton will not help me since if object was changed by someone I want to merge changes of another person and allow conflict resolving. I need a way to find conflicts. The second suggestion I didnt understand, though my objects are not real world entities.

Comment: It was something similar to a singleton. Let's say user U1 creates an object O1 of Class C. Now user U2 wants to create Object O2 of Class C where O1.equales(O2) then rather than creating object O2 you just return cached O1. But I think that might not be useful to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your objects are plain old java beans, then you could use reflection to compare all properties between 2 objects. [Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/) can help with that.

But you'll have to implement some conflict resolution strategy. If the same property has been changed by both clients. The easiest would be "the-latest-change-wins" strategy - a change with latest "lastUpdateTime" overwrites any other change.